# Mapa de mapas: ¿cómo ordenar el mapa interno con lambda?

Tags: java, map, lambda, programación-funcional, collection

Tengo un mapa como este:

> Map<String,Map<String,String>>

Y necesito ordenar el segundo mapa, por lo cual intente esto:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> response = new ArrayList<>();

response.add(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("STATE1"); add("COB2"); add("1"); }});
response.add(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("STATE1"); add("COB125"); add("3");}});
response.add(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("STATE1"); add("COB55"); add("4");}});
response.add(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("STATE2"); add("UI5"); add("100");}});

Supplier<TreeMap<String, String>> typeMap = () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());

Object result = response.stream().collect(groupingBy((ArrayList p) -> p.get(0).toString(), Collectors.toMap(
(ArrayList p) -> p.get(1).toString(),
(ArrayList p) -> p.get(2).toString(), (u, v) -> v,typeMap)));

Map<String, Map<String, String>> finalMap = (Map<String, Map<String, String>>) result;
```

Necesito otro modo de ordenamiento, probe con: `Comparator.naturalOrder()` sin embargo retorna:

`finalMap` = STATE1 => {**COB125**=3, **COB2**=1, **COB55**=4}, STATE2 => {UI5=100}

Pero espero lo siguiente:

`expectedMap`  STATE1 => {**COB2**=3, **COB55**=1, **COB125**=4}, STATE2 => {*UI5*=100}

Comment: Ordenamiento, pero... ¿según qué? ¿Bajo qué criterio? ¿El valor de su `Key`? ¿El valor de `Value`? ¿Numéricamente? ¿Orden lexico-gráfico? Explica al menos cómo quieres ordenarlo porque no queda nada claro de tu pregunta, de hecho ni lo mencionas. Eso explicaría al menos cómo llega ese 3 a  `COB2` en tu `expected`, yo esperaría un 1? Lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: No se si es exactamente lo que quieres, pero prueba remplazando el comparador que tienes en `TreeMap` por este `Comparator.comparing(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")))`. Eso te da como resultado las keys en el orden "esperado".

Comment: Gracias @JaimeMenéndez con respecto a tu pregunta, busco una orden alfanumérico clásico si es que así se le puede llamar, sin embargo me sirve reemplazando el ```Comparator``` tal cual como lo indicaste. Lo que no entiendo es porque se necesita un entero para poder ordenarlo de esta manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El order en que están siendo ordenados las claves es el correcto según el orden natural de los `Strings` en `java` ([orden lexicográfico](http://enciclopedia.us.es/index.php/Orden_lexicogr%C3%A1fico)).

En este orden se va letra por letra comparando caracter por caracter, en cuando encuentre una letra menor, se concluye que el elemento es menor. Bajo el orden lexicográfico `12 < 2` porque se compara primero el 1 con el 2, concluyendo que como 1 es menor que 2 entonces 12 es menor.

De manera similar se cumple que: `3 > 245`, `COB125 < COB2`, `COB2 < COB55`.

Siguiendo esa lógica `COB125 < COB2 < COB55`. Los prefijos no cuentan porque son iguales. Luego viene el 1 con el 2...

Como ves, este el el orden que te está devolviendo, pero por tu requerimientos, en realidad requieres que el orden sea numérico, usando el orden natural del número entero presente en la `Key` del map.

Para ello, cambia el comparador del `TreeMap` por el siguiente:

```
 Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")));
 Supplier<TreeMap<String, String>> typeMap = () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator);
```

Con este comparador, extraes el número de la key y lo conviertes a entero para poder compararlo como número. Paso por paso:

1. Toma el `String`
2. Elimina todo lo que no sea número.
3. Parsea esto a entero.
4. Usa ese valor para el comparador.

Jugando con el comparador, ahora que lo entiendes, puedes lograr cualquier orden que desees.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion muy clara